# WooCommerce Clears Fields On Checkout Validation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, braintree

I got problem with Woocommerce Braintree (by SkyVerge) plugin. Credit card fields are getting empty after validation. Video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X_hAKSCckRg

Anyone?

Comment: You might do well to specify which vendor's plugin. There are maybe up to 10 out there.